# Как добавить проверку на существование элемента в алгоритм бинарного поиска?

Tags: python, алгоритм, двоичный-поиск

Есть алгоритм бинарного поиска, который в зависимости от значения переменной `last` возвращает первое или последнее вхождение элемента в массив

```
def binary_search(l, key, last):
    low = 0
    high = len(l)-1
    while low <= high: 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        midVal = l[mid];
        if (midVal < key or (last and midVal == key)): low = mid + 1
        elif (midVal > key or ((not last) and midVal == key)): high = mid - 1
    return high if last else low
```

Как добавить проверку на существование элемента в алгоритм бинарного поиска?

Comment: `if midval == key:`

Comment: @0andriy разве это означает существование элемента в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, после завершения `while`, можно проверить равенство значений по ключу и при отсутствии вернуть `None`:

```
def binary_search(lst, value, is_last):
    low = 0
    high = len(lst)
    while low <= high: 
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        mid_val = lst[mid];
        if (mid_val < value or (is_last and mid_val == value)): low = mid + 1
        elif (mid_val > value or ((not is_last) and mid_val == value)): high = mid - 1
    else:
        if is_last and high == value:
            return high
        elif not is_last and low == value:
            return low
        else
            return None
```